# Customize login with azure AD

Tags: azure, active-directory, oauth-2.0, office365, adfs3.0

I have a subscription to Office 365 Azure AD, I have developed a MVC application to authenticate by Owin OAuth2.

In such subscription I have 3 custom domain names, I have customized the login page in the configuration option brand, but this changes me for all domains registered in my subscription, implementing a federated server for each domain registered my subscription could customize the login page of each unmodified my development?

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD branding is configured on tenant-level so AFAIK you can't have different branding for the custom domains. You would need to make a separate tenant for them. You *can* set different branding for different cultures but that does not really help with this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really good AAD requirement though!
vote it [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/13439364-allow-different-login-branding-customizations-per)

meanwhile, you'll have two options

1. Create a generic branding with logos from all 3 domains (probably not acceptable)
2. Use ADFS and federate diferent domains to different claims using the *SupportMultipleDomain* switch. Help [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/abizerh/2013/02/05/supportmultipledomain-switch-when-managing-sso-to-office-365/) and [here](http://terenceluk.blogspot.de/2016/03/setting-up-multiple-domain-federation.html)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @evertonmc and @junnas this is tenant level. However, as you suggested, implementing a federated server for each domain would work - But in this case, the customization should be at ADFS level (if ADFS is the IDP) or it depends up on the IDP providers which you would use.